# When to enable repairs after adding new nodes to cassandra cluster?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

I am adding new nodes to my existing cassandra cluster which is running on Vnodes with cassandra version 2.1.16. I had cron jobs scheduled for the repairs to run on these nodes. Before adding the new nodes I had disabled the cron jobs, but I am confused whether I should enable the repairs after both token moves and cleanups are completed or can I enable it after token moves before cleanups?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable your repair jobs after you do the cleanup. I suggest reading [this](http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2017/05/23/auto-bootstrapping-part1.html) article, especially the Gotchas section for the Range movement. If the scenario described there applies to you, then you would need to run repair manually on the node, after bootstrapping.

Answer (score 0):

Once your node added in your existing cluster and new node showing status UN. you can run repair and after this you can run cleanup as well.